# Using Selenium to manipulate code editor platforms (Like Google Earth Engine)

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to manipulate the text inside the code editor platforms (in this case Google Earth Engine) and modify some contents of the code.

the reason is that Google Earth Engine in free version will not allow the user to retrieve data more than a limit (50000 length of data or something like this).
So the user cannot make a loop inside the js code editor to get a long dataset. Instead we can automate the user behaviour by inserting the dates one after another using Selenium, right? But here's my problem.

The html structure does not have any iframes at all but there is lots of "div" and "span". What I want to do is to change the text inside the text box where it gets the date from user to retrieve data based on that date, now I can modify the span value to my desired value (the desired date)
`

```
start_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[17]/span[4]')
```

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = \"'1988-01-01'\"", start_date)
```

`OR`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = \"'1988-01-01'\"", start_date)
```

`
but it's only like you do in inspect window and when I run the script in Google Earth Engine it behaves like the value is not changed (which is obvious). How can I manipulate the text in a text editor platform in general? I've searched the entire web but none was working to me.

I tried to find each element based on their Xpath and kept them as different variables,

Send_keys() does not work
using execute_script() also only changes the value "apparently" (like changing Google to FOOFLE in inspect mode) but not the actual text.

I expect a way to modify the actual text in the code editor of GEE (or a part of it, the dates) and then run the GEE script to retrieve my data based on the new date.

Thanks

Comment: What is the argument that using selenium will not limit you to the ~50.000 api calls?

Comment: Thanks @BasvanderLinden in general you can run the GEE script as much as you want, but you are limited to making a loop inside the GEE script to get a data for a long period (say 20 years).
Instead we can insert the dates one by one and run the script after inserting each date, this is what I'm trying to do using Selenium. Removing the current date and replacing with a new one, running the script and saving the data and inserting a new date and running the script again ...